# dumbbell contour integration

Tags: analysis, contour-integration

I'm looking to evaluate the integral  $$ I= \int_{-1}^{1}  \frac {(1-x^2)^{1/2}}{(1+x^2)} dx $$ by considering the function $ f(z)= \frac {(z^2-1)^{1/2}}{z^2+1}$. Im told that using $ 0 < arg(z \pm 1) <2 \pi $ that we only need a branch cut between -1 and 1 of the real axis.

My method is to compute the integral $J $  for a circle of large radius (using the form of $ f(z)$ for large $z$) and then compute the integral $K$ around the cut, by a dumbbell contour. Then also accounting for the singularities at $i$ and $-i$ we can find the integral we want.

I was just wondering if this is a valid approach to the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is a valid approach. BTW, pay attention to the phase factor coming form $\sqrt{z^2-1}$, it is easy to make mistake there. For your reference, the integral is $(\sqrt{2}-1)\pi$

Comment: Hi, I've got to the point where I'm computing the dumbbell contour and I'm struggling to "argue away" the circles at the ends of the dumbbell. Typically I have been bounding the integrals by showing it to be less than the (length of path x max |f(z)|) and then letting the respective radii of the small circles tend to zero. Is this correct?

Comment: Notice $|\sqrt{1-x^2}| \to 0$ as $x \to \pm 1$. Even if it didn't converge to $0$, as long as it is bounded, the contribution from the small circles of radius $\epsilon$ will be $O(\epsilon)$ and you can forget them.

Comment: Hi, are we able to show explicitly how the circles are of order epsilon, this is what I am finding it difficult to do. Thanks for all your help

Comment: If $|x - 1| \le \min(\epsilon,\frac12)$, then $|x+1| \le \frac52$. This implies  $|\sqrt{x^2-1}| \le \sqrt{\frac{5\epsilon}{2}}$. Furthermore, $|1+x^2| \ge 1 - \frac{1}{2^2} = \frac34$. This leads to

$$\left|\oint_{C(1,\epsilon)} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{1+x^2}dx\right|
\le 
\oint_{C(1,\epsilon)} \left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{1+x^2}\right||dx|
\le \sqrt{\frac{5\epsilon}{2}}\cdot\frac43\cdot 2\pi \epsilon = o(\epsilon)$$

Comment: Hi sorry, where do we get |x-1|<min(e,1/2) from? Is this an assumption we make?

Comment: it is an assumption we make. When one want to bound a factor consists of multiple pieces, different pieces may need different constraints. For example, to bound $|x+1|$, one really should have $x$ smaller than some fixed number instead of $\epsilon$. keeping explicit dependence of $\epsilon$ everywhere may the bound too complicated and hard to analysis.